# nodejs firebase realtime database ordering not work

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some code written in nodejs and it makes use of firebase realtime database to print out some data. I would like them to print out in order, but the orderByChild("adscore2017") is not working.

```
const ref = admin.database().ref('/programmelist');
var speech = "The scores are: ";

ref.orderByChild('adscore2017').on("value", function(snap) {
    var numOfChildren = snap.numChildren();
    for (var i = 1; i <= numOfChildren; i++) {
        var path = ref.child(i);
        path.on("value", function(snap) {
            speech += snap.val().adscore2017+", ";
        });
    }
    app.ask(speech)  //print the output
});
```

This is the structure of my [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACdoO.png). The expected output should be like:

`The scores are 20.8, 21,6, 21.8.....`

but the current output:

`The scores are 21.8, 20.8, 21.6.....`

which is obviously not in order. Someone please help me for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `forEach` loop after retrieved the data will be better, as `for` method is sync looping but you try to retrieve data inside this loop async. So below small changes may work:

```
ref.orderByChild('adscore2017').on("value", function(snap) {
   snap.forEach((s,inx) =>{
      speech += s.val().adscore2017+", ";
   })
   if (inx==snap.numChildren()-1) {
      app.ask(speech)  //print the output
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem!!!! But how to change it to descending order, that is the highest score comes first?

Comment: You may first deploy an empty array then use `array.sort` method. There is no other way at firebase api